# How to send AT commands to HuaweiE3276 using Putty

Tags: putty, serial-port, usb-modem

i am trying to connect with COM port of Huawei LTE modem E3276 with a java program. To test AT commands i am using Putty as terminal application. 
Once i give COM port and all other parameters (Baud rate,parity etc) to default values. though it got connected, but when i type in AT commands there is no reply on sccreen and no error messages also.

can anyone please help me with this... (if Port settings has to be changed , what should be those values)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the firmware used, and how it is configured, the E3276 can have a different amount of serial ports, configured for different usage.

At least one of the serial ports is probably configured to respond to AT-commands, however, echo might be turned off.

Try all of the serial ports and send ATZ and ATE1 and you should get data back on at least one of them.

If you insert a working (with PIN-lock disabled) SIM-card, you might also get RSSI (and other data) printed on one of the serial ports.